# Simulate geometric brownian motion and use generated data for calculations

Tags: probability-or-statistics, simulation

I want to generate a geometric brownian motion A with mean $MuA$, variance $SA$ and starting value 0.05. I do the following:

```
A = RandomFunction[GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[MuA, SA,0.05], {0,12,1}]
```

I also have a time series $X$ generated as follows:

```
x[t_] = 0.1*E^((t - 0)*0.9)
xData = Table[x[t], {t, 0, 10, 1}]
ListLinePlot[xData]
```

[image]

I want to create a third time series as follows (the code is wrong):

```
y[t_]:=x[t]*A[t]
```

In other words, I would like to use the elements of the discrete-time brownian motion in the function y[t]. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is the following:

1- Generate the brownian motion with mean , variance  and starting value 0.05. Time goes from 0 to 5 at intervals of 0.1:

```
ARandom = RandomFunction[GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[MuA,SA,0.05],{0,5,0.01}];
```

Extract only the values (Not the time index) of the GBM:

```
A = Normal[ARandom][[1]][[All, 2]];
```

Use the extracted values of the GBM to do other calculations:

```
Y = A*Table[e^x[t], {t, 0, 5, 0.01}];
```